# Is it possible to run Blazor Client in Kestrel mode at Windows 8.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-8.1, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, kestrel

I am trying to run **Blazor Web Assembly App** on my **Windows 8.1** machine without any succeided. Because of the fact that **Kestrel** mode is not recommended for Windows 8.1 OS, I used in my others samples project (at MVC, Razor Page, Blazor Server and API) such hardcoded in *appsettings.js* notation:

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http1"
    }
  }
```

and it was worked very nice.
But on **Blazor Web Assembly App** there is no any *appsettings.js* file. Instead of *appsettings.js* there is an *launcheSettings.json* file with such an default structure:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55974",
      "sslPort": 44318
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "BlazorClientDemoApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

When I try to hardcode the **Kestrel**'s code mentioned above the application does not appear on the browser.

Is it possible to do it on Windows 8.1 OS.?

specification:

```
Windows 8.1 64bit
VisualStudio 2019: 16.7.6 version,
SDK 3.1.403 Core,
Microsoft .NET Framework Wersja 4.8.03761,
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.7.532.,
ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   16.1.0.,
ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   16.7.532.28833
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood, but you could use "wwwroot/appsettings.json" as counterpart of regular "appsettings.json". When you call something like `builder.Configuration.GetValue...` from your "Program.cs" the values will be taken from this json file.